# Accessing objects from api response

Tags: php, laravel, object

Hello I get an `$response` from an API post request, below is the `$response`

```
LINE\LINEBot\Response::__set_state(array(
   'httpStatus' => 200,
   'body' => '{"richMenuId":"richmenu-5a489c22120e48cec70f3c3cd3b318db"}',
   'headers' => 
  array (
    'server' => 'openresty',
    'date' => 'Thu, 03 Feb 2022 11:31:51 GMT',
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'content-length' => '58',
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
    'expires' => '0',
    'pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'x-content-type-options' => 'nosniff',
    'x-frame-options' => 'DENY',
    'x-line-request-id' => '84ababf8-81e9-4cda-aeb0-25d9b44e9b24',
    'x-xss-protection' => '1; mode=block',
  ),
))
```

Can someone tell me how I could access the "richMenuId" from above object?

I tried to access the object as followed
`$response->body->richMenuId`

This gives me an error:

> `Cannot access private property LINE\\LINEBot\\Response::$body`

I have also tried changing the object to an array using answers on SO but was not able to solve it.

This is probably a noob question but any input is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-php/blob/master/src/LINEBot/Response.php), we see two methods:

- `getRawBody` (https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-php/blob/0500634336ec1b524587a978b917b7b3a3679aef/src/LINEBot/Response.php#L74)
- `getJSONDecodedBody` (https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-php/blob/0500634336ec1b524587a978b917b7b3a3679aef/src/LINEBot/Response.php#L84)

So, one could use either `$response->getRawBody()` or `$response->getJSONDecodedBody()`, depending on which of them fits the requirements better.

## Unsuccessful approaches

My initial idea was to do it via:

```
json_decode(json_encode($response), true)['body']
```

but this does not work, the `private` members are not generated into the JSON. So, instead of that, my next thought was to use Reflection:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('LINE\\LINEBot\\Response');

var_dump($reflectionClass->getProperty('body')->getValue($response));
```

however that did not reach the private property either.

Comment: thanks for your input. But this gives me the error `Undefined array key "body"`.

Comment: @haashe what does `echo json_encode($response);` result in?

Comment: Im not sure if I can use echo or print_r because this is a chatbot just using [LINE API](https://developers.line.biz/en/services/messaging-api/) so without a view to show echo? But I output it using`Log::info(json_encode($response));` and the result is an empty array {}

Comment: @haashe okay, then the `private` stuff is not generated into an output. This means that the `json_`-based approach will not work here. Alternatively, you will need to use reflection. Editing my answer.

Comment: @haashe I have edited my answer with a reflection approach. Please try that and let me know whether it works.

Comment: I tried your method as advised but this time the error is `Cannot access non-public property LINE\LINEBot\Response::$body`.

Comment: @haashe okay, then we need to look at the docs :). I have edited the answer and now I'm sure you will be able to find the content of the body.

Comment: Oh wow cannot thank you enough for this! I did go through the github repo but could not find what I was looking for.